# angular directive does not work with input type = "number"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

The code below works only when the input type is text, and it doesn't work when the type is number.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as model">
 <input type="text"  ng-model="cero" ng-decimal   >   
</div> 


angular
    .module("myApp",[])
    .controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
        var model=this;
    })
    .directive('ngDecimal', function ($parse) {
        var linkFunction =function(scope, element, attrs){     
            element.bind("keypress", function(event) {
                if(event.which === 13) {    
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        scope.$eval(attrs.format, {'event': event});
                        if(scope.cero===undefined || scope.cero===''){
                            scope.cero="0.", 
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }else{

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        };
        return{
            restrict : 'A',
            scope:{
                cero: '=ngModel'
            },
            link: linkFunction
        }
    });
```

What I need help with is changing the type to number and still making the code work. The code is also on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/fernandooj/pen/EgmQmJ?editors=1011).

Comment: You didn't describe your problem or ask a question.

Comment: maybe you should try with `scope.cero="0,"`

Comment: What you are trying to do with the directive. Can you elaborate your question?

Comment: @GangadharJannu  well my question is: how I can make that directive to work me to change the input of text to number

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak , thanks for your answer, but dont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated pen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QKOVkP?editors=1011

Works with number, constraint being you cannot assign

```
scope.cero = "0." // string value
```

to a `type="number"` so replace it with the minimum number you want to assign, maybe

```
scope.cero = parseFloat("0.01")  // parseFloat("0.") won't work
```

Comment: yes perfect, But the condition, so I did not eliminate what the user has written but that no longer works, you know that?

Comment: updated plunker with `alert()` , working both ways, also check the if condition `scope.cero === null` has been added to the conditions
- http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QKOVkP?editors=1011

Answer (score 1):

In the else condition add this.

```
scope.cero = parseFloat(scope.cero).toFixed(2);
```

Convert string to decimal

Here is the code: [working code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGOdda?editors=1011)

Comment: thanks for this code, but if i change the input to type number dont work http://codepen.io/fernandooj/pen/amVaQm?editors=1011